# Can't resolve symbol, Animations

Tags: android, animation, android-edittext

Ive found some code that works for a Edit text animation but it gives a cleaner code with it to use with a. animation res file which works but for me it does not. the Anims.this causes a error in the code and I can't figure out why. Searching online for the issue doesn't resolve anything cause it looks like no one else has had and issue like this or this one in particular.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText mSearch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //finding View
    mSearch = findViewById(R.id.search);


}

public void onEdit(View view) {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Anims.this,     R.anim.edittext_scale);
    mSearch.startAnimation(anim);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the resource of `loadAnimation` method

> public static Animation loadAnimation(Context context, int id)
>   {}

So the first param is `Context` .And in your code,`Context` is `MainActivity` .So you should use `MainActivity` instead of `Anims` .

Change

```
public void onEdit(View view) {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Anims.this,     R.anim.edittext_scale);
    mSearch.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

to

```
public void onEdit(View view) {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.edittext_scale);
    mSearch.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Comment: This works though the animation resets after the code has completed. Is there a way to make it so it holds till say another onClick method is called then it goes to normal size. Aswell is there a specific code that I can use to reset it instead of onClick, set.Width(200);, set.height(40)

Comment: Good luck to you.@EquiWare